# Toss a coin repeatedly and independently. Show that heads eventually appears. Show that any fixed finite sequence such as HTHHHT eventually appears?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

I'm not getting the answer for the second part where I have to prove about the fixed finite such as HTHHHT will eventually appears. Please help me with this part.

Comment: How did you show that heads eventually appears?  Why wouldn't the exact same approach work for HTHHHT?  In short, more details, please.

Comment: How did you answer the first part? Tell us, then you will know how to work out the second part.

Comment: The second part is not too bad if you have a good solid explanation for the first part.  However, the first part is a bit tricky, because it isn't impossible to have tails every time.  You need to be precise about what you mean when you say that heads eventually appears (there is a difference between probability zero and physically impossible).

Comment: Do you know about infinite monkey theorem?    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_monkey_theorem                                          go to solution part  and read the proof. I have strictly followed this theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you know the Borel-Cantelli lemmas?  In particular, the second one?

It says that if $E_1,\ldots,E_n$ are independent events, and
$$
P(E_1)+P(E_2)+\cdots=\infty,
$$
then with probability 1 infinitely many of the events $(E_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ occur.

What if $E_n$ is "elements $6n+1,\ldots,6n+6$ are HTHHHT"?

You could, of course, come up with a proof that doesn't use Borel-Cantelli.  For any $n$, $P(E_n)=\frac{1}{2^6}$, and these events are independent. Using this, what's the probability that *at least one* event $E_1,\ldots,E_n$ occurs?  What does this probability do as $n\to\infty$?

Comment: so the answer should be 1 if I go by the method " For any nn, P(En)=126P(En)=126, and these events are independent." as P(at least one them occurs = P(neither one of them occurs) i.e., P(at least one them occurs = P(neither one of them occurs)= 1-1/2^6=63/64. Now we have to find P(Un=1 to infinity En)=1-P(intersection from n=1 to infinity En complement), it will give 1. Am I right?

Comment: there's a little error in the first line of my last comment. It is "for any n, P(En)=1/2^6, and these events are independent."

Comment: The probability that at least one event occurs is $1-P(E_1^C\cap E_2^C\cap\cdots\cap E_n^C)=1-(1/2^6)^n$.

Comment: The $n$ there is key; because then, as $n\to\infty$, this probability converges to $1$.  But yes, otherwise, the argument is correct!

Answer (score 0):

Let $X_n$ denote the event that the particular $6$-long pattern occurs starting at position $n$, so $P(X_n)=1/2^6$.

Let $Y_n$ be the event that none of the events $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ occur. It is tempting to claim that
$P(Y_n)=(1-1/2^6)^n$, but this is false! $X_i$ and $X_j$ are dependent if $|i-j|<6$, since the two windows overlap.

However, if $|i-j|\ge6$ then $X_i$ and $X_j$ **are** independent, as they depend on distinct dice throws. So we have
$$P(Y_n)\le P(\neg X_n) P(\neg X_{n-6}) P(\neg X_{n-12})\cdots = (1-1/2^6)^{\lfloor n/6\rfloor}\to 0$$
as $n\to \infty$. Thus the pattern will eventually appear "almost surely" (i.e. with probability one.)